# Facebook comments results in javascript error in Safari for iPhone and iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, facebook-comments, x-frame-options

I have a problem with Facebook comments, which doesn't work on Safari for the iPhone.
The Facebook comments works nicely in most browsers, but I get a Javascript error in Safari on the iPhone.

I have created a minimal test-case here, which shows the problem:
http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~andrearo/fotball.html

I get the following error message in Safari on the iPhone:

**"Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options".**

Could someone please give some advice about how to get this Facebook Comments to work on Safari for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

This was asked years ago, but I was recently having the same issue and found a solution. It seems that the comments tag needs to have the data-href tag to prevent this.

If you use:

```
<div class="fb-comments"></div>
```

Most platforms will use the current page url and have no issues.

For iOS, use:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.google.com/"></div>
```

With the appropriate URL, of course, and the comments work without error.

Hope this helps.